# Within Dubai, is duty-free gold cheaper for comparable quality from the local Souk?

Tags: dubai, duty-free

I am spending some time in Dubai but not enough to visit the souk.  I would like to purchase Gold at a reasonable rate.

Since I am not able to buy it from Gold Souk/ Local Dubai Market I am considering the duty-free Gold within the airport.  Is it cheaper than the souk?

Comment: Do you mean jewelry, or bullion?

Comment: Voting to leave this closed [since it looks like a shopping question](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question) to me.

Comment: Why is this "opinion-based"?  The airport has effectively a single monopoly seller, it should be quite easy to factually determine how their prices compare against prices in the souk and/or the public price of gold.

Comment: I have edited this to make it more quantitative and factually answerable.